# How do I create a folder in start menu?

Tags: installation, start-menu

I just installed a virtual audio cable software that came with away too many utilities that are now all over the app list in the start menu.
Is there a way to **create a folder** to group them in, just like the ones which are hinted at when installing some software?

My main objective is to tidyup the app list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to `%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, and create a new sub-directory in there. You'll see it come up when you click Start, and you can then move shortcuts into that folder.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, Thank you.